# can you fill in the gaps in this service bus description?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm new to service buses and trying to get a better understanding of the details.  Consider the following statement:

> "If the max delivery count for a message is exceeded for a
>   subscription then the messaging system places the message on the dead
>   letter sub queue"

Please confirm if my following understanding is correct:

- A service bus has topics
- Topics have subscribers
- When a message is added to a topic then this message gets pushed to subscribers

Can you explain the concept of "max delivery count" in this context?  Can you name a specific object type in Azure which attempts to deliver this message?  I'm guessing that a failed delivery means that the subscriber is offline or is in some state where it doesn't receive the message or rejects the message?  Is this correct?

If the service bus encounters an internal error when attempting to deliver the message then I'm assuming that this would not count towards the "max delivery count" number, right? Can you generically describe the process in which the bus attempts to send the message to the subscriber but delivery fails?  What are the common response types to this send attempt which would increment the failed delivery count number? Also, can you describe the process for accessing the dead letter subqueue in Azure?

Comment: Using a question title that's actually descriptive of your question will help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Max delivery count indicates the maximum number of times a message can be delivered. If a specific message is not successfully processed by receivers for 'n' number of times, then it will be moved to a dead letter sub queue (place where you can find the failed messages with failure reason).The count is incremented when a message lock expires, or the message is explicitly abandoned by the receiver.

Circumstances under which messages get moved to dead letter queue can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues)

Messages in dead letter path can be received using following code:

```
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var deadLetterPath = SubscriptionClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(topicPath,subscriptionName);
var Receiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver(deadLetterPath, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```